# How to convert a JSON object containing an array to C# Dictionary<string,string>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, winforms, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am sending a request to a WebAPI using following code:

```
client.PostAsync(baseAddress + path, new FormUrlEncodedContent(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,string>>(form)))
```

where `client` is an object of `HttpClient` class. This code is executed for all the requests to the WebApi. I am trying to send following data to the API:

```
{
    "code":"GUEST",
    "category":"Indian",
    "sections":["01000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","02000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"],
    "date":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "time":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "quantity":1.0,
    "price":0.0,
    "discount":0.0,
    "paymentMethod":"ID",
    "paymentMethodID":null,
    "ticketNo":null
}
```

Now because the `FormUrlEncodedContent` accepts only the `Dictionary<string,string>` object, I am converting this JSON into that type using NewtonSoft's JSON.NET method `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`. But at the point where `sections` array starts, it is showing me this error message:
`Unexpected character encountered while parsing value:[. Path 'sections'`.

So, what approach should I follow if I want to use the same code for this kind of JSON data?

Comment: You won't be able to send this as FormUrlEncodedContent. Can't you simply send the json as a body of your post request, not URL-encoded?

Comment: @Pac0 Actually the API only accepts in this format. I tried other ways but no luck. Also, other methods are passing the data in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you for any reason need to send all values as strings, then you must convert array of strings to string before deserializing it to `Dictionary<string, string>`.

It can be done like this:

```
var json = "{\"code\":\"GUEST\",\"category\":\"Indian\",\"sections\":[\"01000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\",\"02000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\"],\"date\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"time\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"quantity\":1.0,\"price\":0.0,\"discount\":0.0,\"paymentMethod\":\"ID\",\"paymentMethodID\":null,\"ticketNo\":null}";

var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
jObject["sections"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jObject["sections"].ToObject<string[]>());

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jObject.ToString());
```

That way you will get result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks :) This worked. Although I modified the logic to incorporate this. But it's working fine now.