# How can I deserialize a nested object in JSON.NET for FormUrlEncodedContent?

Tags: c#, json.net

The API I am working with requires JSON data, but also requires that the data be sent in the Content-Type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded' so I am deserializing to a dictionary to pass the body to FormUrlEncodedContent. Everything was reasonably well with the world until I had to send a body that wasn't a flat structure.

I was reading the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53315488/how-to-convert-a-json-object-containing-an-array-to-c-sharp-dictionarystring-st), and thought that I had stumbled upon the solution to my problem, but I'm getting the following error:

```cs
Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path 'filters[0]', line 1, position 165.
```

I am reasonably sure before I tried this method, the position was position 164, so at least I've made some progress before falling on my hands and knees here.

Here's an example of what I am doing.

**Objects:**

```cs
public partial class SearchRequest
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    JsonProperty("fieldId")]
    public string FieldId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("fields")]
    public string[] Fields { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("filters")]
    public Filter[] Filters { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("pageNumber")]
    public long PageNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("searchText")]
    public string SearchText { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sorting")]
    public Sorting[] Sorting { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("promptValues")]
    public PromptValue[] PromptValues { get; set; }
}

public class Filter
{
    [JsonProperty("fieldId")]
    public string FieldId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("operator")]
    public string Operator { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class PromptValue
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("collectionValue")]
    public string CollectionValue { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("promptId")]
    public string PromptId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public Value Value { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
}

public class Sorting
{
    [JsonProperty("fieldId")]
    public string FieldId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("direction")]
    public long Direction { get; set; }
}
```

**Method:**

```cs
Dictionary<string, string> dictBody;
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest
{
    // Do stuff
}
string body = Serialize.ToJson(searchRequest);
var jObj = JObject.Parse(body);
jObj["filters"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jObj["filters"].ToObject<string[]>());  // Problem encountered here.
jObj["sorting"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jObj["sorting"].ToObject<string[]>());
jObj["promptValues"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jObj["promptValues"].ToObject<string[]>());
dictBody = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jObj.ToString());
```

**JSON Sample:**

```
{
    "id": "blah",
    "fieldId": "blah",
    "fields": [
        "blah"
    ],
    "filters": [
        {
            "fieldId": "blah",
            "operator": "eq",
            "value": "blah"
        },
        {
            "fieldId": "blah",
            "operator": "eq",
            "value": "blah"
        }
    ],
    "pageNumber": "blah",
    "searchText": "blah",
    "sorting": [
        {
            "fieldId": "blah",
            "direction": "eq"
        }
    ],
    "promptValues": [
        {
            "id": "blah",
            "collectionValue": "blah",
            "promptId": "blah",
            "value": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

Can someone help? Even better, is there way of automatically recognising the embedded objects and flattening them?

Comment: Can you share the sample JSON you are trying to deserialize?

Comment: Added a JSON sample as requested))

Comment: Did you try [c# Build URL encoded query from model object for HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47466758)?

Comment: @dbc Sorry for the newb question, but would that ToKeyValue() method need to be on the SearchRequest class I defined above for the parameter (this object blah) to work? The linked answer had it on an ObjectExtensions class, but the linked site from there doesn't.

Comment: Well it's an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) so you would do `var dictBody = searchRequest.ToKeyValue();`

Comment: I will try this out now. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @dbc works perfectly. Appreciate your patience with the additional question. I'd be happy to accept this as an answer if you want to post it below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tested your case and came up with the following solution:

The code below should come after your `SearchRequest` class.

```cs
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

When you have your class, you do the follwing:

```cs
Dictionary<string, string> dictBody = new Dictionary<string, string>();

var properties = searchRequest.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
foreach (var prop in properties)
{
    var valueAsObj = prop.GetValue(searchRequest);
    var valueAsString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(valueAsObj);
    dictBody.Add(prop.Name, valueAsString);
}
```

This will fill your `Dictionary<string, string>`. Here is an example:
[image]

Hope this helps,
Cheers :)

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer. I really appreciate that you tested it too. I've upvoted, but already found a working solution from the comments above.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the positive answer. :) Upvoted as well